# exclude certain records from laravel scout/algolia

Tags: laravel, algolia

I am using laravel scout to upload records for searching in algolia. I have added the searchable trait to my model, and everything is working fine.

There is a case now where I don't want to add certain records to my index if they have set status I.E UNPUBLISHED.

is there away I can evaluate the status field and decide if I want the model to be uploaded to the index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `$model_name->unsearchable()` to remove it from your Algolia index.

See "Removing Records" in the documentation for more details: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scout#removing-records

Comment: I know i can do this on a model save, I was hoping to embed the functionilty with in the model itself to keep things neater.

Answer (score 3):

You can use method [`toSearchableData()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scout#configuring-searchable-data) and in case the status is Unpublished, just return empty array and the record will be skipped.
Otherwise just return `$this->toArray()`.

It will do the trick.

Comment: If i do that it still makes the call to agolia, but it is blank. Is there a way to stop it calling out?

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a **Post** model, with a boolean **published** attribute, and a model factory to seed our table as follows:

```
$factory->define(App\Post::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    $tile = $faker->realText(50);
    $date = $faker->dateTime;

    return [
        'title'     => $tile,
        'body'      => $faker->realText(500),
        'published' => $faker->boolean(80),
        'created_at' => $date,
        'updated_at' => $date
    ];
});
```

Let's say we will seed 10 records.

```
public function run()
{
    factory(App\Article::class, 10)->create();
}
```

If we tried to exclude **unpublished** records within the *toSearchableArray()* method, as suggested:

```
public function toSearchableArray()
{
    if (! $this->published) {
        return[];
    }

    // ...
}
```

When seeding the **posts** table, instead of ignoring **unpublished** records by returning an empty array, scout will keep asking the model factory for a **published** model.

For example, if two of the seeded records were randomly **unpublished**, scout would index all 10 records (instead of 8) anyway, replacing the **unpublished** ones by a new model factory (with a **published** set attribute). Thus causing to have two inexistent (on our table) records in the algolia index. Quite confusing.

The "neatest" way around this I could come up with, was to listen to the saved/updated events (saving/updating won't cut it) in the model's boot method.

```
protected static function boot()
{
    static::saved(function ($model) {
        if (! $model->published) {
            $model->unsearchable();
        }
    });

    static::updated(function ($model) {
        if (! $model->published) {
            $model->unsearchable();
        }
    });

    parent::boot();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question. This problem has been solved in the new version of Scout 
[Adding Index to Laravel Scout Conditionally (Algolia)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48191954/adding-index-to-laravel-scout-conditionally-algolia/48202820?noredirect=1#comment83431508_48202820)