# Adding Index to Laravel Scout Conditionally (Algolia)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, algolia, laravel-scout

I'm trying to add index to Algolia using Laravel Scout based on a condition. For example I have a `Article` model and I only want to add this article to Algolia if the article is `active`. My first approach was this:

```
public function toSearchableArray()
{
   if($this->active) return $record;
   return [];

}
```

this only adds the active records but still attempts to add empty arrays which is considered as Operation in algolia ( I will be charged for it). The second approach was to use `shouldBesearchable()` function from scout:

```
public function shouldBeSearchable()
{
    if($this->active) return true;
    return false;

}
```

This doesn't work with `php artisan scout:import "App\Article"`. Has anyone faced a similar problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a bug in Laravel Scout, `shouldBeSearchable` is not release yet (on master branch) so you may experience some issue like this one.

Although, good news: it was just fixed by this PR.
https://github.com/laravel/scout/pull/250

Comment: awesome! Thanks.

Comment: Feel free to upvote my answer and mark it as _solution_ ;)

Comment: The version was updated 15 days ago, yet shouldBeSearchable still isn't working for me, any reason as to why?

Comment: Are you using the master branch? I don't thing it's "released" (tagged) yet.

Comment: @ZachHandley put this in your composer json: "laravel/scout": "dev-master"